# Joomla Contacts display misc Informations on main contact page

Tags: joomla, contacts

im new to Joomla and i do understand the concept of overrides. I want to customize the contact page.
On default there is a tab with 
"misc. informations" `<span class="contact-misc">
                        <?php echo $this->contact->misc; ?> 
</span>` in "contact/default.php"

i wanted to display that on the first page of the contacts. so the user does not have to click on the contact to be forwarded to the contacts page with the contact form and the misc informations. when i try to copy the code into "category/default_items.php" i get an error ("Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in D:\xampp\htdocs\joomla\templates\protostar\html\com_contact\category\default_items.php on line 105") 
thats because i'm using components from another component. So my question is: is there a way to combine those both components, so i can use fragments from one  in the other?

Answer (score 1):

You certainly can, but you need to carefully read the layout. In the default_items layout, you have a loop:

```
<?php foreach ($this->items as $i => $item) : ?>
...
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

So, within the loop, you have to reference each item as **$item**, e.g.

```
<span class="contact-misc">
    <?php echo $item->misc; ?> 
</span>
```

Comment: Okay i tried to copy the whole foreach loop, but still the same problem. How can i combine them? do i need to include one component as php into the other or could you please explain it to me?

Comment: I never told you to copy the whole foreach loop. I'm sorry but there's not a more clear / simple answer to that.